# How to get plain html from textarea

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to get data from textbox in plain HTML i.e if i write Hello World then it should return

> `Hello&nbsp;World`

. I dont want to use HtmlEditor can i get plain html using textArea?

Comment: If "Hello World" is entered into the TextArea, then "Hello World" is the value.  The user didn't enter a "&nbsp;" so there isn't one present.  Note that "Hello World" is just as much "plain HTML" as "Hello&nbsp;World" is.  I suppose you could replace spaces with "&nbsp;" values, but there's no reason why the control would do that for you.

Comment: Without a Html Editor how would you allow users to enter `<p>` `<h1>` `<h2>` `<h3>`?

Comment: I want to get only pre, enter, space tags

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/encode-html-string

If you really need the `&nbsp;` you can always string-replace spaces

Comment: I want it for all operations like space,enter,pre etc

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to need to transform the text manually (with `string.Replace()` or something similar) to accomplish this.  Consider, for example, the "enter" and "space" tags you're looking for.  If the user enters this as plain text (such as in a `TextArea`):

```
Hello World
Another line
```

Then that's precisely the value that's in the `TextArea`.  The user didn't enter this:

```
Hello&nbsp;World<br />Another&nbsp;line
```

That's an entirely different string value.  A WYSIWYG HTML editing control (and there are many for ASP.NET) would do some of the text transforms for you.  At least it would probably convert the carriage returns into break tags for you.

But I doubt it would convert every space into a non-breaking space, since that's a very different value than what was entered.  You'll likely have to do that yourself.  (And be aware that converting all spaces into non-breaking spaces might not render the output like you expect.  Look forward to a lot of horizontal scrolling.)

HTML isn't a translation of text into another medium, it's markup that's included in the text.  Both of my examples above are perfectly valid HTML.  One of them just doesn't include any markup tags.